# click event on HTML select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to listen a `click` event in the event. The `change` event is only fired when I select other items, but I need an event to be triggered even I click the selected one.

For example, when I select `Apple`, `change` event triggered. Then I select `Apple` again, I need an event to be triggered as well.

```js
$("#fruit").on('click', function() {
  console.log("click event");
});

$("#fruit").on('change', function() {
  console.log("change event");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fruit">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why not only change?

Comment: @Justcode because `change` event will only be triggered if the element actually changes.

Comment: [`jQuery.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: I don't believe in the modern era of all things code this is possible. `change` is about your best without over complicating things. Sure there's arduous workarounds if you wish to take that route. If you don't care what the select looks like, click is actually supported if you add a `size` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I solve that problem wrapping the select element with a div element and using the onclick over the div, after that the function javascript call the select element using the id, like this:

HTML:

```
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<div onclick="ReadSelected()">
    <select id="fruit">
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="Pear">Pear</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function ReadSelected(){
    var selectedValues = $("#fruit").val();
    console.log(selectedValues); //if you select apple will be ['Apple']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

> **The change event is sent to an element when its value changes.** This event is limited to  elements,  boxes and  elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

As there is no change when you click on 'Apple' when 'Apple' is already selected, it looks like the 'click' event is your best option. Why exactly do you need the change event to fire when you click the same option? Maybe there is a better solution than firing the change event in this case?

Comment: The `click` event is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You may check condition on click like below to achieve what you want .

```js
var flag = false; 
$('#fruit').on('click', function() {
  if (flag) {
    console.log($(this).val()); 
    flag = false;
  } else {
    flag = true;
  }
}).on('blur', function() {
  flag = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fruit">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what browser are you using? `click` on `select` doesn't work for me on Chrome 71.

Comment: Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) and its work perfect like as snippet.

Comment: I am using the same version as well. Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit). So weird.

Comment: No, there is nothing on my console, so the event was not even triggered.